# how to view my website from anywhere which is running in my laptop at home.?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

Things I did so far.

my website is running on port 80.

had opened my port 80 with the help of VPN book. confirmed with canyouseeme.org.

Created an account in noip.com. Created a hostname.

using the AsusZenfone3 mobile phone and airtel 4g mobile data. getting internet to my laptop via Hotspot/Tethering using wifi from phone and laptop.

had downloaded DUC from noip and it is running fine.

had configured a device in noip.com for my host like below,
- hostname

- router brand as Asus(I don't use any router/ I don't know what router is used)
  -software/device as HTTP
- Is there any computer running on your network? Yes
- downloaded Duc
- port 80 check success
- my host has been successfully configured.

I also added rules to my firewall to enable TCP and UDP 80 port access.

But still, I am not able to access my website.

I tried calling my website from the proxy server, I get an empty result from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say for certain, but it sounds like you opened port 80 on your router but likely did not forward that port to an address on your local LAN.

Somewhere in your router config you should be able to find a port forward option. So any traffic received on that port would need to be forwarded to the local IP of the computer running the webserver.

## Problem

Your port is not forwarded through your gateway connection.

## Solution

[Fwd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elixsr.portforwarder&hl=en) Port Forwarding app for Android phone

Comment: As i already mentioned, i dont know what router is used. I am using airtel 4g cellular/mobiledata tethering. I tried connecting using the default gateway mentioned in the ipconfig, but it didnt work. how to configure portforwarding when mobile data is used?

Comment: Mobile data from which type of device? Android or iOS?

Comment: Just a quick follow up. If you are running your mobile data through an iOS device you are, as they say, SOL. iOS does not allow you to port forward through its personal hotspot.

Comment: I already mentioned my mobile phone details. i dont think any of ASUS zenfone 3 uses  iOS. Its Android 7.0.  Anyway i am upvoting for your efforts.

Comment: So you can use an android app to port forward. Take a look at the play store for Port Forward. Then you basically configure your phone to pass traffic received on its public IP to the private IP of your webserver.